# Find and replace file/folder names and contents in whole Linux file system

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, replace, filesystems

I have a Linux (Ubuntu) server on which I am hosting a website. I am changing my domain name, let's say from `xxxxx.xx` to `yyyyy.yy`.

What I would like is a find `xxxxx.xx` and replace it with `yyyyy.yy` **both in all file and folder names and in all file contents across the whole file system** to reflect this change.

I don't believe this question has been asked in its entirety, but if I've missed it please point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: How would you expect us to find files with pattern `xxxxx.xx`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question; `xxxxx.xx` is an exact string I want to match, not a pattern.

Comment: Are files/directories named `xxxx.xx`?

Comment: They may be, or it may be included in their name if that's what you're getting at.

Comment: Can you provide a couple of actual file/folder names of this type?

Comment: Also, I would be grateful if whoever is downvoting my question could explain the issue with it so I can improve it.

Comment: I did not down-vote BTW

Comment: Downvoting because question asks for code with no demonstrated effort. We help *you* write the code. Not just write it all for you.

Comment: For example, there is one file I know of called `xxxxx.xx` but I would also want to match `anythingxxxxx.xx` and `xxxxx.xxanything`.

Comment: @kaylum I expect my question has quite a simple one line answer. Whilst I did research ways of possibly achieving this, they are more complicated and do not do exactly what I want so I feel it would be more confusing to include them.

Comment: Still, show what you have done and explain how it doesn't work or why you think it is not good enough. That will show your effort and give people a reference on what your thinking is and then be able to suggest how it can be improved or alternate solutions.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GNU find` and a bit of `bash` string manipulation for actual file-renaming.

`*xxxx.xx*` is a glob-pattern to match files/folders having this anywhere in their names.

Strictly recommend **NOT** to run the re-name straight away, but run with `echo` once to see if the files are listed properly. Am providing two different commands, one for renaming files and other for folders, because renaming folders needs couple of extra options to avoid recursive file-renaming.

For re-naming folders:-

```
find . -depth -type d -name "*xxxx.xx*" -execdir sh -c 'x=$1; y="${x/xxxx.xx/yyyy.yy}"; mv -v "$x" "$y"' sh {} \;
```

For files:-

```
find . -type f -name "*xxxx.xx*" -exec sh -c 'x=$1; y="${x/xxxx.xx/yyyy.yy}"; mv -v "$x" "$y"' sh {} \;
```

Do **NOT** run the commands right away, just run the below commands, to see if the original file/folder and the re-named file/folder have proper names as you intended.

```
find . -type f -name "*xxxx.xx*" -exec sh -c 'x=$1; y="${x/xxxx.xx/yyyy.yy}"; echo "$x" "$y"' sh {} \;
```

(and)

```
find . -depth -type d -name "*xxxx.xx*" -execdir sh -c 'x=$1; y="${x/xxxx.xx/yyyy.yy}"; echo "$x" "$y"' sh {} \;
```

Since you want to change the contents of file also, add an extra `sed` in-place file re-naming as

```
find . -type f -name "*xxxx.xx*" -exec sh -c 'x=$1; y="${x/xxxx.xx/yyyy.yy}"; mv -v "$x" "$y"; sed -i 's/xxxx.xx/yyyy.yy/g' "$y" ' sh {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out!

Comment: @Zak: do let me know if it worked, and don't forget to accept the solution to mark it useful for further reference.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. I think it is working although I don't want to try the "live" version yet as I don't want to rename quite yet. I'll definitely accept your answer once I'm sure it's working.

Comment: What about file contents?